# dojox data grid - hook to find if the header checkbox is selected or not

Tags: datagrid, header, checkbox, dojo

In a multiple selection grid, is there a hook to check if the check box in the header is checked or unchecked.
Currently to see if all rows are selected, i am using grid.selection.getSelected().length which returns the no of selected rows and with more that 2500 rows in grid, IE throws script error.
To optimize we just need a hook to check if the header checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

`grid.selection.getSelectedCount()` works without loading all the items.

`getSelected()` with indirect selection attempts to load all the items.